# Update of range in Pivotcaches not saved after running macro

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I have a pivot-table in excel of which I want to update the sourcedata-range via macro. Until recently, the following code was working:

```
Dim oBereich As Range
Dim oPT As PivotTable, oPTrpt As PivotTable
Dim oPC As PivotCache, oPCrpt As PivotCache

Set oPT = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1)

Set oPC = oPT.PivotCache
Set oPC = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:="'" & ActiveSheet.Name & "'!" & oBereich.Address(, , xlR1C1))

oPT.RefreshTable
```

Here `oBereich` is a cell-range object which has the correct range.

For some odd reason, the code does not seem to update the range any longer due to some version problem (maybe?). It does not throw an error either, so I do not know what is going on.
I've checked all the surrounding objects like `ActiveSheet`and `.PivotTables(1)`, they seem fine. 
Any idea how I can make this work?

Comment: Side and unrelated note - good use of an R1C1-style address string for `SourceData`! Have seen multiple questions with people using a `Range` object, which causes issues.

Comment: I think you need to [`ChangePivotCache`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.pivottable.changepivotcache).

Comment: Yes: `Set oPT = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1)
oPT.ChangePivotCache ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:="'" & ActiveSheet.Name & "'!" & oBereich.Address(, , xlR1C1))`